# UWP Parallax with offset

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, parallax, windows-community-toolkit

I develop UWP application with listview of images with translucated items background like on Windows Phone Start screen (e.g.  https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/larger/public/field/image/2014/04/Clean_vs_Busy.jpg?itok=58NioLgB).
I decided to base my solution on [UWP Community toolkit parallax service](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations/ParallaxService.cs).
First I took left-top point of item:

```
var p = parallaxElement.TransformToVisual(scroller).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

Where should I add this offset in animation expression? Also I did not find full documentation for this.

```
 ExpressionAnimation expression = compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation(
        "Matrix4x4.CreateFromTranslation(Vector3(HorizontalMultiplier * scroller.Translation.X, VerticalMultiplier * scroller.Translation.Y, 0.0f))");
    expression.SetReferenceParameter("scroller", scrollerViewerManipulation);
    expression.SetScalarParameter("offsetX", (float)p.X);
    expression.SetScalarParameter("offsetY", (float)p.Y);
```

In other words, I'd like to make effect "looking through items on shared large image"; items are wholes in canvas.

Comment: Are you trying to animate one image under a grid view of items (like WP home screen)? Or are you trying to animate your all of your images in your "listview of images"?

Comment: I'd like to animate some/all of images of listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate all of the images of your list, you can follow the [sample from the Windows Composition team](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/6ed79c3ee7d31bcb41509ba37569aef6aa0306c7/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2010586/ParallaxingListItems/ParallaxingListItems.xaml.cs).

Here's the tl/dr version:

Create the animation. Do this when the page is loaded:

```
private void SetupAnimation()
{
    // available with SDK version 15063
    Compositor compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
    // available with previous SDK version
    //Compositor compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

    // Get scrollviewer using UWP Community Toolkit extension method
    ScrollViewer myScrollViewer = ImageList.FindDescendant<ScrollViewer>();
    _scrollProperties = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(myScrollViewer);

    // Setup the expression
    var scrollPropSet = _scrollProperties.GetSpecializedReference<ManipulationPropertySetReferenceNode>();
    var startOffset = ExpressionValues.Constant.CreateConstantScalar("startOffset", 0.0f);
    var parallaxValue = 0.5f;
    var parallax = (scrollPropSet.Translation.Y + startOffset);
    _parallaxExpression = parallax * parallaxValue - parallax;
}
```

Animate each image in the list when the container changes (**NOTE**: subscribe to the ContainerContentChanging event of your ListView)

```
private void ImageList_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    // Find the image element to animate
    Image image = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot.GetFirstDescendantOfType<Image>();

    Visual visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(image);
    // You'll want to use the right size for your images
    visual.Size = new Vector2(960f, 960f);

    if (_parallaxExpression != null)
    {
        _parallaxExpression.SetScalarParameter("StartOffset", (float)args.ItemIndex * visual.Size.Y / 4.0f);
    visual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", _parallaxExpression);
    }
}
```

This sample works with a ListView or GridView.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Could you advise how to add startOffsetX to this solution and make animation Offset.XY?

Comment: You could add another animation "Offset.X" just like the Offset.Y one